# ASP.MVC Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

My frontend validation appeared to have stopped accross my site and even if I create new controllers + views all of my forms when clicked posts straight to the server without checking the local generated (the default jqueryval validation built into the MVC framework). This returns into either a thrown expression but it states that there are validation errors when attempting to update.

1. This is happening on all of my forms, even new controllers
2. I have had some database + EF6 changes / updates, but the validation rules are still in place (see below sample model)
3. There is no javascript error in console
4. The jqueryval script is loaded into DOM so it's present
5. I have noted that in the controller ModelState.IsValid returns true when there were obvious validation errors (which is usually thrown by EF)

I am happy to provide source code but to be honest I am not sure of what exactly as this really only started this week. I am leaning towards something not updating (not sure) but any help would be appreciated. Comment if you want to see specific code, will gladly update question.

Controller POST:

```
// POST: Codes/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Create([Bind(Include = "id,CountryId,TPrintBw,TPrintCol,TCopyBw,TCopyCol,TFax,TScan")] Code code)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    db.Codes.Add(code);
                    await db.SaveChangesAsync();
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {

                }

            }
            ViewBag.CountriesList = new SelectList(db.Countries.ToList(), "NumCode", "CountryName");
            return View(code);
        }
```

CREATE RAZOR:

```
@model regusPrintMan.Models.Code

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
    ViewBag.Section = "Country Codes";
}

@section Styles {
    <!-- BEGIN PAGE LEVEL STYLES -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/global/plugins/select2/select2.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/global/plugins/datatables/plugins/bootstrap/dataTables.bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-datepicker/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/global/plugins/datatables/extensions/Scroller/css/dataTables.scroller.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../assets/global/plugins/datatables/extensions/ColReorder/css/dataTables.colReorder.min.css" />
    <!-- END PAGE LEVEL STYLES -->
}

@section JS {
    <!-- BEGIN PAGE LEVEL PLUGINS -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../assets/global/plugins/select2/select2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../assets/global/plugins/datatables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../assets/global/plugins/datatables/plugins/bootstrap/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../assets/global/plugins/datatables/extensions/TableTools/js/dataTables.tableTools.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../assets/global/plugins/datatables/extensions/ColReorder/js/dataTables.colReorder.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../assets/global/plugins/datatables/extensions/Scroller/js/dataTables.scroller.min.js"></script>
    <!-- END PAGE LEVEL PLUGINS -->
    <!-- BEGIN PAGE LEVEL SCRIPTS -->
    <script src="../../assets/global/scripts/datatable.js"></script>
    <script src="../../assets/admin/pages/scripts/table-ajax.js"></script>
    <!-- END PAGE LEVEL SCRIPTS -->
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            Layout.init(); // init current layout
            Demo.init(); // init demo features
            TableAjax.init();
        });
    </script>
    <!-- END JAVASCRIPTS -->
}

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}

<!-- BEGIN PAGE HEAD -->
<div class="page-head">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- BEGIN PAGE TITLE -->
        <div class="page-title">
            <h1>@ViewBag.Section <small></small></h1>
        </div>
        <!-- END PAGE TITLE -->
    </div>
</div>
<!-- END PAGE HEAD -->
<!-- BEGIN PAGE CONTENT -->
<div class="page-content">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- BEGIN PAGE CONTENT INNER -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <!-- Begin: life time stats -->
                <div class="portlet light">
                    <div class="portlet-title">
                        <div class="caption">
                            <i class="fa fa-gift font-green-sharp"></i>
                            <span class="caption-subject font-green-sharp bold uppercase">Create Country Codes</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tools">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="portlet-body">
                        @using (Html.BeginForm())
                        {
                            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

                            <div class="form-horizontal">
                                @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CountryId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                                    <div class="col-md-10">
                                       @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CountryId, (SelectList)ViewBag.CountriesList, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CountryId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TPrintBw, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                                    <div class="col-md-10">
                                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TPrintBw, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TPrintBw, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TPrintCol, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                                    <div class="col-md-10">
                                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TPrintCol, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TPrintCol, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TCopyBw, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                                    <div class="col-md-10">
                                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TCopyBw, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TCopyBw, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TCopyCol, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                                    <div class="col-md-10">
                                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TCopyCol, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TCopyCol, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TFax, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                                    <div class="col-md-10">
                                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TFax, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TFax, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TScan, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                                    <div class="col-md-10">
                                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TScan, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TScan, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                                        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        }
                        <div>
                            @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- END PAGE CONTENT INNER -->
    </div>
</div>
<!-- END PAGE CONTENT -->
```

Comment: Could you post your Code class?

Comment: Could you copy the content of the EnityValidationErrors property?